# Synchronization on an instance in java

Tags: java, synchronization

I have an object named "Plan". There is an interface called "PlanService" that provides APIs to call CRUD operations on "Plan". PlanServiceImpl is the implementer which actually implements CRUD operations on Plan.

Now I want to synchronize the CRUD operations on Plan in such a way that if callerA is calling "createPlan", callerB should wait before callerA is done creating the Plan before calling on any other operation on the plan.

I've seen a couple of links on this but don't quite understand the differences between synchronization mechanisms as explained here :

http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/synchronized.html

Can someone please explain to me which method would serve the purpose?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The crucial question lies around how many instances of your service exist. If your service is a singleton (only one instance in your application) then you can synchronize like this:

```
public void synchronized createPlan() {

}
```

Since the object holding the lock will be the same wherever the method is called from.

If it's not a singleton then you need a single object to synchronise on:

```
public void createPlan() {
    synchronized(PlanServiceImpl.class) {

    }
}
```

This is commonly the `class` object, since there will be a single instance of this within the JVM.

Comment: Yes the service is a singleton. Edit to the question: When callerA is calling "createPlan", callerB should wait before callerA is done before calling on ANY other operation on the plan.

Comment: In that case, all you have to do is add `synchronized` to all CRUD methods on the service class.  They are locked on the same instance of your service,

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you only want to stop other threads while the plan is being created and allow multithread access otherwise. It sound to me like you are looking for a `ReadWriteLock` which allows you to make some areas *writing* and therefore no other thread can access while other areas are *reading* meaning no other thread can *write*.

Something like this:

```
class Plan {

    ReadWriteLock creating = new ReentrantReadWriteLock();

    public void createPlan() {
        // Establish a write lock - no-one else can read or write while I hold this lock.
        creating.writeLock().lock();
        try {
            // Do your creating here.
        } finally {
            creating.writeLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void doSomething() {
        // Establish a read lock - no-one else can write while reading in process.
        creating.readLock().lock();
        try {
            // Do your creating here.
        } finally {
            creating.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }

    public void doSomethingElse() {
        // Establish a read lock - other threads can also take a read lock at the same time.
        creating.readLock().lock();
        try {
            // Do your creating here.
        } finally {
            creating.readLock().unlock();
        }
    }
}
```

Here methods `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` can run in parallel but they will block is `creatPlan` is being done.

Comment: I think I didn't explain the question well. Apologies for that. When callerA is calling "createPlan", callerB should wait before callerA is done before calling on ANY other operation on the plan.

Comment: @Natasha - That is what will happen here. Both `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` will block if `createPlan` is in progress. Here also `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` do not block each other where they would if you just used `synchronized`.

Comment: So for a blocking call, is "synchronized" enough or RW Lock is necessary?

Comment: @Natasha - If you are happy with `doSomething` blocking `doSomethingElse` even when `createPlan` is **not** in progress then yes, `synchronized` would be sufficient.